# What are the hidden subgroups in roles in Heroes of the Storm?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I thought that Quick Match would try to match you against another team with a similar composition. For example, if one team gets [1 support + 1 warrior + 3 assassins] the other team would also get such a composition.

However, in one of his videos, [MFPallytime](https://www.youtube.com/user/MFPallytime) mentions that the reworked Tyrande (still *Support*) will be matched against another "sustain" heroes, which could even mean he'd be "mirrored" in the other team by an Abathur (a *Specialist*), or a Medivh (also a *Specialist*).

My own recent experience seems to support the hypothesis that there is such a different, more fine-grained grouping of heroes that is used to create "mirror-ish" matchups in Quick Match.

Is this correct, and if so: what are the hidden groups and what heroes do they contain?

Comment: I would like to point that Quick Match is supposed to mirror compositions (not exactly, like 1 team can have 2 of something while the other team has one) but you need to keep in mind due to the sacrifice of keeping the match making "quick" the game won't always match team compositions.

Comment: Ah yeah, I understand. That might make things hard to reverse engineer based on personal / anecdotal evidence. But I was hoping someone would (a) know of an official source for info, (b) know of a way to distill this from public matchmaking data, (c) had found this e.g. in the game files somewhere, or (d) ...?

Comment: Well [Hotslog](https://www.hotslogs.com/Default) does have a list of roles beyond the 4 listed in-game I just don't know what constitutes as the "right" answer.  Although I have heard Blizzard developers use terms like "bruiser" and what not so clearly you can focus roles down more than Warrior, Assassin, Support & Specialist.

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/307732/99134

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The updated quickplay matchmaking roles are described [here](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/heroes/topic/20753597280). The names I'm using aren't official.

> **Healer** - The game tries to prevent 1-2 healers teams from going up against 0 healer team. Any "Support" hero that isn't in the Sustain group goes in this group.
>
> **Sustain** - Again, the game tries to mirror the amount of Sustain heroes on each side. The heroes in this group are Abathur, Tyrande, Tassadar, Zarya and Medivh.
>
> **Tank** - Also mirrored. Contains all warriors except Zarya, D.Va and Sonya. Currently includes Varian, but I think this has been changed twice already, and might change again.
>
> **Bruiser** - Not mirrored. Might not do anything actually. Includes Sonya, D.Va, Ragnaros and Thrall. [Ref](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/heroes/topic/20754876032)
>
> **Stealth** - Not mirrored. Teams are limited to one stealth character each, to prevent Nova/Zeratul/Valeera as your three dps. Also includes Samuro. There's a [theory](https://www.reddit.com/r/heroesofthestorm/comments/6jh4sv/genji_has_abnormally_small_matches_played_with/) that Genji is also included in this, but this hasn't been confirmed.

The older rules which may or may not be still be effect are described [here](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/15145471/matchmaking-design-in-heroes-of-the-storm-8-8-2014)

> No more than 3 Warriors.
>
> No more than 4 Assassins.
>
> No more than 2 Support.
>
> No more than 2 Specialists.
>
> No more than 3 Melee heroes.

I don't have details about how these two sets of rules interact with each other, or how the older ruleset might have been updated.

Comment: If someone has a link for the Varian change patch, or more detailed notes about how mirroring works I'd love to include them.